# Why do string index signatures enforce that all properties match their return type?

Tags: typescript

From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type.

Then they show this interface:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

My question is - why does `name` have to be a subtype of the indexer? What if I have an object where everything but `name` is expected to be `number` while `name` is `string`?

Then, the docs say:

> This is because a string index declares that `obj.property` is also available as `obj["property"]`.

If `name` is `string` and not `number`, I can still access it with both `obj.name` and `obj["name"]`? I don't see how this makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see how this makes a difference.

Because the latter, `obj["name"]` goes through the indexer property, at least potentially. A better example might be:

```
declare let s: string;
console.log(obj[s]);
```

...since there it's clear that we're using a string and not a string literal `"name"`. Indexer properties let you do that, whereas without an indexer property [you get an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjaARYBMYAexDigE9kBvAKAHoHkXkBtUAEwgA8AuZAGcwUUAHMAugJBZcUANx1WyADYQQYsAAtps6IuXlMEAcNEbFAXzp01YZPzR6oBIqXJVkAXlpqN2gQAGABpkIxNkACIYEhJIy0VuBBUKFDshUxFxRQQyQRI1ADoVEjEACh42QQkASnkgA) if you do that:

> ```
> interface NumberDictionary {
> //    [index: string]: number;       commented out indexer
>     length: number;
>     name: string;
> }
>
> let x: NumberDictionary = {length: 0, name: "foo"};
> declare let s: string;
> console.log(x[s]);
>             ^^^^
>             Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'NumberDictionary'.
> ```

Since all properties are accessible that way, they must all have the same type.

Comment: I see. So this is kind of a typescript limitation because types are checked at compile time when the value of `s` is not known and therefore, the element's type is not known either. I think that would've been much easier to understand if the docs compared `obj.property` with `obj[someValue]` instead of `obj["property"]` because typescript could actually read the latter and know the element's type at compile time (since its key is a string literal and not some unknown value). Is that right?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov - I'd agree, yes. After all, if you use a string *literal*, you don't need an indexer.